# printing in a for loop with JS

Tags: javascript

I need to print a div with a for loop in javascript, I know that the issue might be related to the *async functionality* but I am not able to solve the issue? any tips? (adding alert will allow me to print all the iterated divs)

```
function printmex(){
var qty=document.getElementById("qtr").value;

for(var i=0;i<qty;i++){
var rc="receipt"+i;

var divToPrint1=document.getElementById(rc);
newWin2= window.open("","newWin2","width=1,height=1");
newWin2.document.write(divToPrint1.outerHTML);
newWin2.print();
newWin2.close();
}
}
```

Comment: add setTimeout 100  to whichever needs lag

Comment: You immediately close the window in the loop. Maybe remove the close line. I would advice to do the following as well: `qty=Number(document.getElementById("qtr").value);` and `for(let i=0;i<qty;i++){`

Comment: IMHO this should rather not be done opening a litany of popups to begin with. Use a proper print stylesheet that eliminates everything you _don’t_ want to print, and then just let the user print the page “normally” …

Comment: @HMR this didnt help. please note that adding the alert statement makes the divs print individualy

Comment: @misorude  i need that in a for loop where each div has its own id, how can this be added in the script?

Comment: @ACD Timeout not helping, can you advise how to add it to my snippet?

Comment: _“i need that in a for loop where each div has its own id”_ - surely those elements have something else in common that could be used to select them …? (And even if they don’t, selecting elements based on that their id starts with a specific prefix is also easily possible.) _“how can this be added in the script”_ - my suggestion was to _not_ use any script to begin with …

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code help you

```
function printmex(counter) {

  const win = window.open('', 'win', 'status');

  for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    const box = win.document.createElement('div');
    box.innerText = counter.toString();
    box.id = counter.toString();

    win.document.body.appendChild(box);
  }

  win.print();
}

printmex(5);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however this didn't yield in printing anything

Comment: @SCOTT, [example in jsbin](https://jsbin.com/gixerov/1/edit?html,js,output)